# Spring prototype to singleton and get the value in another class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
@Component
scope("prototype")
Class A{

}
```

Class **A** is of bean scope prototype

```
@Component
Class B{

@Autowire
private A a;

 public A getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

}
```

Class **B** is of bean scope Singleton have getters and setters of **A**

```
Class C{

@Autowire
private B b;

// other code

b.setA(a);

}
```

In class **C** the  **B** is autowired and set the object of **A**

```
Class D{

@Autowire
private B b;

// How can I get the value of A which is set in C
//something like

A a= b.getA();

}
```

How can I get the value of A using B in Class D using spring Annotations or using XML

Comment: If *A* is a bean you should annotate the method *getA()* in cass *B* with the annotation *@Bean*

Comment: I miss this: you have or not *B* in class *D*?

Comment: Yes B in class D

Comment: how does A get into A? Is it injected? I see no corresponding anntotation on the field `a` and no constructor. Same question for B in D.

Comment: How can I make the correct Annotations and get it working? @P.J.Meisch

Comment: Yes B in class D  edited the code @MarioSantini

Comment: I think you need to add more explanation here. Not sure why you need that class *A* should be a *Component* and if so, why a *prototype* scope? Why you don't put the logic to create *A* in *C* as looks like it is the place where you create *A*. More, I think your issue is actually with the timing *A* is set and get. Not sure, more infos are nedded here to cover the issue.

Comment: The project I work now has a similar requirement @MarioSantini, Yes It's about the timing, I am not sure whether I will get the A object in D using B

Comment: @CorkKochi If is about timing, you need to use a flag that tell you if *A* is ready/done. If you have to build it on the fly (sorry, don't know the details here), you should change your code accordingly, putting all in *C* and access it to bould *A* when you need.

Comment: Can you show me with correct Annotation, if you don't mind, please @MarioSantini

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can understand from your OP, in your project you want to separate component *D* from component *C*, or you just have a situation where you cant produce component *A* without involving both *C* or *B*.

The issue here, is you miss to explain better your case.

As I wrote in comments a lot of infos are missed here.

My first suggestion is: ask yourself if component *A* should really be a component at all.

You annotate the class with the *scope("prototype")*, this means every time you access the bean you get a new instance of it.

But only if you access through the Spring framework.

The logic you had exposed in your OP it will not work for sure, as you access a normal java object.

Keep in mind that if, for some reason, *A* is just instantiated in a proper time, than you could get a *null* value, and have to handle it accordingly with your business logic.

You have to get the *A* instance or try to build it, when you need to use it.
I know you're thinking you do it in *D*, but not in *B*, where *A* is saved and so you point to a potential wrong object.

I suggest you to remove the dependency of *A* in *B*.

In component *C* add the annotation *@Configuration*, and then you should create a method annotated with *@Bean* like:

```
@Bean
public A getA() {
     // put here the code to create A and that involves B
     return a;
 }
```

Then from your component *D* you could just get the *A* bean by access to the application context [here](https://spring.io/understanding/application-context) you have some details about how to do it. But keep in mind that it is not suggested as a best practices.

All those considerations are speculation about what you wrote so far, and a lot of details that could invalidate all are missed.

Please share a more detailed issue for a proper answer. I just hope this helps you to figure out to understand better your situation at least, if could not solve it.